# Django rest how to do pagination with PageNumberPagination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

I wrote the following codes. But when I go to the url `posts?page=1`, it still shows all of the Post model objects. What should I do?

---

settings.py

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

ursl.py

```py
path('posts', views.posts_view, name='posts_view')
```

views.py

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def posts_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing a function based view, using [`@api_view`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view), so you need to do the pagination manually.  You can try using the [provided generic base api views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) instead of attempting to re-write this, if it works in your situation:

```
class PostView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination

path('posts', PostView.as_view(), name='posts_view')
```

To do pagination manually you are going to need to create and invoke the pagination just like the base classes do:

```
def my_view(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    pagination = PageNumberPagination()
    page = pagination.paginate_queryset(qs, request)
    serializer = PostSerializer(page, many=True)
    return pagination.get_paginated_response(
        serializer.data
    )
```

To be clear, using [@api_view](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) does support other framework features using additional decorators, e.g. `@permissions_classes`.  View level features like pagination & filtering are not supported via decorators.